# In Hybris can I change attribute modifier from unique to not unique

Tags: java, validation, primary-key, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris.
I want to make an existing attribute *not unique*. Currently, the attribute code is declared as `unique=true`.
What could possibly go wrong if I change it to `unique=false`, assuming I have taken care of the corresponding Java code.

Comment: Don't know the tools you are using so cannot comment specifically, but primary key is unique by definition in a database.  If the column you want to change is declared as a PK, you might have some problems at the database end.

Answer (score 0):

At least 1 attribute must be unique. Otherwise, you can't refer to it easily, especially in impex. A PK can be unique, but it's not going to be the same in all environments (Development, Staging, Production).

```
UPDATE CustomType;code[unique=true];name
;CODE1;Name1
;CODE2;Name2
```